# Rails sum on an associated record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a survey model that works like so:

> ResponseSets have many Responses
>   Responses belong_to Answer
>   Answer model has a "value" column.

Given a ResponseSet, I'd like the sum of the Answers that are associated with each Response.

Ie, what I'd *like* to be able to do, (in imaginary code) is:

```
response_set.responses.answers.sum('value')
```

However, this obviously doesn't work, I need to build a query through `response_set.responses`, but I don't know how.

What's the SQL-fu way to tackle this in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I came up with this relatively simple solution, I hope this helps others in the future:

```
response_set.responses.joins(:answer).sum('answers.value')
```

To make this more convenient I just made this a method in the `ResponseSet` Model:

```
def total_value
  self.responses.joins(:answer).sum('answers.value')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using Rails 3.2 you can do something like:

`response_set.responses.answers.pluck(:value).inject{|sum,x| sum + x }`

Comment: Not sure you can do "...responses.answers..." as suggested above given the relation in OP.

Comment: You're right. You could write an "answers" method in the ResponseSet model that returns an array of answers based on responses and then applies the formula to that. Like `response_set.answers.pluck(:value).inject{|sum,x| sum + x }` 
That's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Are the answers Integers, in the sense that you're looking to find ALL numeric answers associated with a response and literally add them all up?  I think you could use map and inject for something like this, depending exactly on how your models/associations are set up..

```
response_set.responses.answers.map(:&value).inject(:+)
```

Can you post your models?